# How do i echo a chunk of html with php

Tags: php, html

Basically what I want to do is this...

If column (seperate_sitting_yes) in row ($rows1) in table = 'yes' echo this chunk of html. Else echo this other chunk of hmtl (I have used an echo statement "nothing" for ease.

```
if ($rows1['seperate_sitting_yes'] == "No";){


                echo 

                <div id="complete_info_wrapper">
                    <div id="complete_info_title"><p>Monday</p></div>
                    <div id="complete_info_details"><p><? echo $rows1['opening_monday_from'];  echo $rows1['opening_monday_to'];/p></div>
                </div>

                <div id="complete_info_wrapper">
                    <div id="complete_info_title"><p>Tuesday</p></div>
                    <div id="complete_info_details"><p><? echo $rows1['opening_tuesday_from'];  echo $rows1['opening_tuesday_to'];/p></div>
                </div>

                <div id="complete_info_wrapper">
                    <div id="complete_info_title"><p>Wednesday</p></div>
                    <div id="complete_info_details"><p><? echo $rows1['opening_wednesday_from'];  echo $rows1['opening_wednesday_to'];/p></div>
                </div>

                <div id="complete_info_wrapper">
                    <div id="complete_info_title"><p>Thursday</p></div>
                    <div id="complete_info_details"><p><? echo $rows1['opening_thursday_from'];  echo $rows1['opening_thursday_to'];/p></div>
                </div>

                <div id="complete_info_wrapper">
                    <div id="complete_info_title"><p>Friday</p></div>
                    <div id="complete_info_details"><p><? echo $rows1['opening_friday_from'];  echo $rows1['opening_friday_to'];/p></div>
                </div>

                <div id="complete_info_wrapper">
                    <div id="complete_info_title"><p>Saturday</p></div>
                    <div id="complete_info_details"><p><? echo $rows1['opening_saturday_from'];  echo $rows1['opening_saturday_to'];/p></div>
                </div>

                <div id="complete_info_wrapper">
                    <div id="complete_info_title"><p>Sunday</p></div>
                    <div id="complete_info_details"><p><? echo $rows1['opening_sunday_from'];  echo $rows1['opening_monday_to'];/p></div>;

                }

                else {echo "nothing";}
```

But i'm not sure how to address this correctly. Can anyone shed any light on the matter. Please and thank you.

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: You're echo syntax for this case is not correct. With so much html in the code, you are better off doing it outside PHP and using pure HTML while using PHP in between as you're already doing.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Comment: ^Agreed with @Maximus2012, better of closing off the PHP tags in the if case and letting pure HTML do most of the lifting and inject PHP echos where needed.

Comment: In your current code, if you just put the php opening/closing tags: `<?php` and `?>` in the correct places then that should work.

Comment: `<p><? echo $rows1['opening_monday_from'];  echo $rows1['opening_monday_to'];/p>` that and all the others are not closed off properly and are missing the closing `?>` and a `<` for the `/p>` which should read as `<p><? echo $rows1['opening_monday_from'];  echo $rows1['opening_monday_to']; ?></p>`

Comment: Plus, make sure that short open tags are enabled. Otherwise, change all instances of `<?` to `<?php`

Comment: If you have error reporting turned on for your PHP code then that should also show you errors with your code which I think are there.

Comment: You also don't have any wrapping quotes for your echo. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, which will show you the parse errors.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer bellow. Basically you need to echo the entire html as a string via php. So you have to put the entire code in a '' quotes and plus you are attaching php variables in it so you can concatinate it via '.'

```
if ($rows1['seperate_sitting_yes'] == "No")
    {

            echo '<div id="complete_info_wrapper">
                <div id="complete_info_title"><p>Monday</p></div>
                <div id="complete_info_details"><p>'.$rows1['opening_monday_from'].''.$rows1['opening_monday_to'];'</p></div>
            </div> 
             <div id="complete_info_wrapper">
                <div id="complete_info_title"><p>Monday</p></div>
                <div id="complete_info_details"><p>'.$rows1['opening_tuesday_from'].''.$rows1['opening_tuesday_to'];'</p></div>
            </div>
            <div id="complete_info_wrapper">
                <div id="complete_info_title"><p>Monday</p></div>
                <div id="complete_info_details"><p>'.$rows1['opening_wednesday_from'].''.$rows1['opening_wednesday_to'];'</p></div>
            </div>
            <div id="complete_info_wrapper">
                <div id="complete_info_title"><p>Monday</p></div>
                <div id="complete_info_details"><p>'.$rows1['opening_thursday_from'].''.$rows1['opening_thursday_to'];'</p></div>
            </div>
            <div id="complete_info_wrapper">
                <div id="complete_info_title"><p>Monday</p></div>
                <div id="complete_info_details"><p>'.$rows1['opening_friday_from'].''.$rows1['opening_firday_to'];'</p></div>
            </div>
            <div id="complete_info_wrapper">
                <div id="complete_info_title"><p>Monday</p></div>
                <div id="complete_info_details"><p>'.$rows1['opening_saturday_from'].''.$rows1['opening_saturday_to'];'</p></div>
            </div>
            <div id="complete_info_wrapper">
                <div id="complete_info_title"><p>Monday</p></div>
                <div id="complete_info_details"><p>'.$rows1['opening_sunday_from'].''.$rows1['opening_sunday_to'];'</p></div>
            </div>';

            }

            else {echo "nothing";}
```

Comment: *here is your answer* An answer with no explanation!

Comment: ^ exactly. They may as well just copy [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992637/how-do-i-echo-a-chunk-of-html-with-php#comment48104988_29992637) @Rizier123 *Meep meep!*

Answer (score 0):

Try letting HTML do most of the heavy lifting and insert PHP echos where needed.

```
<?php if ($rows1['seperate_sitting_yes'] == "No";){ ?> //Close off PHP here

    <!-- This is all HTML here -->

    <!-- Below is HTML code injected with PHP variable -->
    <div><?php echo $variableThatNeedsToBeInserted ?></div>

<?php }else {echo "nothing";} ?> //Closing PHP tag for end } bracket, and else case.
```

Hope this gives you an idea!

Comment: It appears there's a bunch more syntax problems in OP's code.

Comment: so i just store the html under a variable?

Comment: @SpringheeledJack I would not recommend that for your case.

Comment: No need, you can write raw HTML code in between the two PHP segments. Like how in my example, there are <div> tags and in between them you just call PHP to echo your variable <?php echo $var ?>

Comment: SO what is stored under $variableThatNeedsToBeInserted

If not that chunk of HTML...

Comment: @SpringheeledJack what ever that needs to be outputted. It's similar to your echos in between the <p> tags in your code. So I guess whatever `$rows` array is storing in `<p><? echo $rows1['opening_monday_from'];  echo $rows1['opening_monday_to'];/p>`

Answer (score -1):

In your first line there is an ";" that doesn't need to be there...
Instead of

```
if ($rows1['seperate_sitting_yes'] == "No";){
```

Try

```
if ($rows1['seperate_sitting_yes'] == "No"){
```

The ";" denotes the end of a line of code in PHP. When you are trying to evaluate something in an if statement, that is not the end of the line. So remove it, and be sure that `$rows1['seperate_sitting_yes']` is producing expected results.

And as said in other comments, seperate out the PHP and the HTML see the modified code below

```
<?php
$rows1['seperate_sitting_yes'] = "No";
if ($rows1['seperate_sitting_yes'] == "No"){


                ?>

                <div id="complete_info_wrapper">
                    <div id="complete_info_title"><p>Monday</p></div>
                    <div id="complete_info_details"><p><? echo $rows1['opening_monday_from'];  echo $rows1['opening_monday_to'];?></p></div>
                </div>

                <div id="complete_info_wrapper">
                    <div id="complete_info_title"><p>Tuesday</p></div>
                    <div id="complete_info_details"><p><? echo $rows1['opening_tuesday_from'];  echo $rows1['opening_tuesday_to'];?><p></div>
                </div>

                <div id="complete_info_wrapper">
                    <div id="complete_info_title"><p>Wednesday</p></div>
                    <div id="complete_info_details"><p><? echo $rows1['opening_wednesday_from'];  echo $rows1['opening_wednesday_to'];?></p></div>
                </div>

                <div id="complete_info_wrapper">
                    <div id="complete_info_title"><p>Thursday</p></div>
                    <div id="complete_info_details"><p><? echo $rows1['opening_thursday_from'];  echo $rows1['opening_thursday_to'];?></p></div>
                </div>

                <div id="complete_info_wrapper">
                    <div id="complete_info_title"><p>Friday</p></div>
                    <div id="complete_info_details"><p><? echo $rows1['opening_friday_from'];  echo $rows1['opening_friday_to'];?></p></div>
                </div>

                <div id="complete_info_wrapper">
                    <div id="complete_info_title"><p>Saturday</p></div>
                    <div id="complete_info_details"><p><? echo $rows1['opening_saturday_from'];  echo $rows1['opening_saturday_to'];?></p></div>
                </div>

                <div id="complete_info_wrapper">
                    <div id="complete_info_title"><p>Sunday</p></div>
                    <div id="complete_info_details"><p><? echo $rows1['opening_sunday_from'];  echo $rows1['opening_monday_to'];?></p></div>;

                <?php }

                else {echo "nothing";}
?>
```

Comment: That's only half of the cake! OP has more errors in his code

Comment: Yes, Rizier123, I didn't catch that until I did a fiddle with it. I have updated it